# ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN AFTER does not add my column after specified column Delta table

Tags: sql, databricks, delta-lake, alter-table

I want to add a column to my delta table via Databricks SQL. Following the syntax on the Microsoft site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/update-schema and Databricks site https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html
However, in every situation the column was added at the end of the schema instead of at the defined place. I can't figure out what is going wrong.

I tried the following:
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMNS (test STRING FIRST)
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN (test STRING FIRST)
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN test STRING FIRST
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN test STRING AFTER col1
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN test STRING AFTER `col1`
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN test STRING AFTER `table_name.col1`\

And the same with data-type DECIMAL and DECIMAL(16,2)

---- UPDATE ---- 
The problem seems to be related to the type of table you are working on. I could add my columns in the specified locations for an external table in my azure blob storage. However for a managed table in the dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/, I was not able to add the columns in the desired location.

Comment: how do you check if it's at beginning or at the end?

Comment: Select * from table, DESCRIBE TABLE and I checked the schema in the data explorer. All showing the column at the end